# Where is the inlet for the APU on a Fokker 70/100?

Tags: apu, fokker-100

I can see the exhaust for the APU on a Fokker jet, but where is the inlet?

Comment: Can you provide pictures of the specified aircraft please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [this report](https://reports.aviation-safety.net/2015/20150120-2_F100_HB-JVE.pdf) from the BFU.

I reproduced the image of page 12 of the report here

Obviously, the exhaust is in the middle of the picture and the inlet is on the top right part (trapezonidal shape)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, my son will sleep better now. That was a tricky one without having a clear photo of it.

Comment: You're welcome !