# What Is this on the fuselage of The Fokker F100?

Tags: feature-identification, fuselage, fokker-100

[image]
What Is  this on the fuselage of  The Fokker F100?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the inlet for the APU on a Fokker 70/100?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51031/where-is-the-inlet-for-the-apu-on-a-fokker-70-100)

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's the apu exhaust ... there is a post about it:

[Where is the inlet for the APU on a Fokker 70/100?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51031/where-is-the-inlet-for-the-apu-on-a-fokker-70-100)

[image: apu exhaust]